# Julia: waited longer than @time

Tags: julia

I am trying to do in parallel some stuff. Based on @time the performance is excellent, but I am actually waiting quite long in front of my computer.
The code is something like below.

```
function max(n)    
    rand_n = SharedArray{Float64}(n, n)

    @distributed for i in 1:n
        @distributed for j in 1:n

            r = Random(Uniform(), 100)
            rand_n[i,j] = StatsBase.maximum(EV0)

        end
    end
    rand_n
end

@time max(1000)
```

> 0.000166 seconds (118 allocations: 18.203 KiB)

```
tick()
max(1000)
tock()
```

> 2.865833086s: 2 seconds, 865 milliseconds

So the actual time elapsed on the computer is much longer that what @time says.

Comment: my guess is that you're seeing compilation times

Comment: Thank you for your response! I don't think that's my question. The first time I run the function it takes about 0.015 seconds. This should be when Julia compiles the code for the first time. Then the second time I run the function, it takes less than 0.0002 seconds. But my question is that, physically I feel it takes much longer than that. It is not like in matlab that there isn't a too big difference between what the computer tells me and what I feel. Sometimes for Julia @time tells me that the function takes 1 second when I actually have to wait for more than 10 seconds.

Comment: I know `btime` will do this since it runs your code many times to get accurate timings, but a simple `time` call really shouldn't do this. That's really weird

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation of `@distributed` (type `?@distributed` at the prompt):

> Note that without a reducer function, `@distributed` executes
>   asynchronously, i.e. it spawns independent tasks on all available
>   workers and returns immediately without waiting for completion. To
>   wait for completion, prefix the call with `@sync`, like :
>
> ```
> @sync @distributed for var = range
>       body
> end
> ```

Currently, you are just starting the calculation and bailing out, so you get the timing of *starting* the calculation without waiting for it to *finish*.

A couple of more things:

- Please always provide a "minimal working example" so that other posters can just copy-paste your code, and it will run. So include `using Distributed` and other required packages. Define all variables, etc. What is `EV0`, what does `Random` mean here? etc. etc.
- You're defining `r` but you're not using it. What's it for?
- `max` is the name of a function in Base, it's probably not a good idea to overload that name like this.